# Efficient way to test ODBC connection

Tags: c++, sql-server, database, odbc

Our product is a TCP listening transaction processor. Incoming connections are assigned a thread to handle the connection and a DB connection to work with.

Rather than costly approach of establishing new DB connection for each incoming client connection, we maintain a pool of database connections.

The database connection pool fairly configurable: min / max sizes, growth rates, etc.

Some details:

- Platform is Windows 2003 / 2008 R2
- DB is SQL Server 2005 / 2008 R2
- Connection method is ODBC
- Programming language is C++

*Finally*, the question:

As the service could be running for several months without a restart, there's a real chance that some of the database connections in the pool become invalid. I want to have as quick a way as possible to test the validity of a given connection before assigning it to an incoming connection.

Currently, I do this by executing the simple SQL statement "SELECT 123;", however I've found that this has significant negative performance impacts when parallel execution plans are used.

Very briefly in code, what I'm doing is:

```
// ... at some point we decide pool needs another connection...

// Set up database connection
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &conn);
SQLDriverConnect(conn, 0, in_str, in_len, out_str, DIM(out_str), &out_len, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);

// 'conn' is placed in DB connection pool

// ... some time later a new client connection comes in ...

// Execute simple statement to test if 'conn' is still OK
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, conn, &stmt);
SQLExecDirect(stmt, (SQLCHAR*)"SELECT 1;", SQL_NTS);

// If 'conn' is OK, give it to incoming connection;
// if not, get another connection from pool
```

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: I think your only option here may be to simply check the connections more often, but not as often as every time. Perhaps every 5 minutes or so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well the official way is SQLGetConnectAttr( SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_DEAD ) which tests if the connection was working when last attempted.

Or SQLGetConnectAttr(conn, SQL_COPT_SS_CONNECTION_DEAD, ...) which tests if the connection is working now.

Comment: Hi Nick, A better way is:  SQLGetConnectAttr(conn, SQL_COPT_SS_CONNECTION_DEAD, ...) as this tests if the connection is working now. SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_DEAD only tests if the connection was working when last attempted. Thanks for the initial pointer though - it got me on the right track. Cheers, Dave.

Comment: I think the second one is windows specific since in unixODBC there is no such definition and I can find only "SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_DEAD". Is it expected to be that way (maybe a newer ODBC spec version)?

Comment: @a1an it's MS SQL Server driver specific